# In Drupal 8 I accidentally deleted the sign in field. How can I sign in from the home page in the browser? Or from CLI?

Tags: drupal

I was editing the fields that are displayed in my home page.  I removed the Login field. It's like I erased the door knob to get into my house: now there is nothing to click.  Is there a way to log in without clicking a link in my Drupal 8 site homepage?

I tried `http://localhost:7009/admin/content` in the browser and also just `http://localhost:7009/admin/`.  Drupal page shows "Access Denied" message.

How can I sign in as an admin (or anything) now?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. In the browser this:  `http://localhost:7009/user/login`

Answer (score 0):

as you found, you should always be able to log in at `/user/login`

if you're using drush, there are also user commands that allow you to generate a one time log in token, create new users, change passwords, etc.

see: `drush user-login` (alias `drush uli`) https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-login/